# How to speed up the update query on MySql for millions of records

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table which has 27 million id columns.
I plan to update the average and count from another table which is taking very long to complete.

Below is the update query (Database - MySQL, I am using Python to connect to the Database)
 `UPDATE dna_statistics
            SET chorus_count = 
            (SELECT count(*) 
            FROM dna B
            WHERE B.music_id = <music_id>
            AND B.label = 'Chorus')
            WHERE music_id = 916094`

Comment: you can write a python script that will make this work in batches

Answer (score 1):

As scaisEdge already said, you need to check if there are indices on the two tables.

I would like to add to scaisEdge's answer that the order of the columns in the composite index should match the order in which you compare them.

You used

```
    WHERE B.music_id = <music_id>
AND B.label = 'Chorus')
```

So your index should consist of the columns in order (music_id, label) and not (label, music_id).

I would have added this as comment, but I'm still 1 reputation point away from commenting.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** clause isn't good solution for 27 millions id's

use **EXCHANGE PARTITION** instead

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have a cmposite index   on

```
 table dna   column ( label, music_id)
```

and a index  on

```
table  dna_statistics column (music_id)
```